# Change grub bootloader for another distro's bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader

I have a dual boot set up, with Arch and Ubuntu. Arch was my first OS, so over there I have `refind`, a bootloader for UEFI systems that I prefer aesthetically to grub. When I installed Ubuntu, each time I log in and reboot, it removes `refind` as the default and boots me to `grub`. How could I fix this?

I tried `refind mkdefault` in Arch, but didn't work

It's also the default in my BIOS

Comment: Only if you do a grub update, would it reinstall and then set itself as default. You need grub to be able to boot, but not as boot manager. Grub probably replaced /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi with a copy of grubx64.efi or shimx64.efi and you want that to be rEFInd's version. Check file sizes in EFI/Boot. You can change default in UEFI to be rEFInd, Arch or the drive which uses the /EFI/boot folder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a dangerous solution: just uninstall GRUB.

Edit: just looked around and people are saying it is either laborious or impossible to remove. There are some solutions like *hiding* the GRUB screen or even just disabling rather than removing. I managed to get my rEFInd bootloader working instead of GRUB, so if you need any config files, let me know.

Comment: I tried to uninstall `grub`, but as you said, it was reallyl unintuitive. For example, `sudo apt remove grub` doesn't work, neither with `sudo snap remove grub`. Also, I would prefer not to reinstall `refind` on ubuntu, but I may have to do just that. Maybe that would fix it?

Comment: That might work? Not really sure if I am honest. My installation was smooth and GRUB is still enabled. Now and again when GRUB gets an update, I have to change boot priority, but apart from that it is rather smooth sailing.

Comment: If you are going to reinstall rEFInd, follow the instructions down to the T to make sure you aren't missing anything.